# "Linked lists" in numpy array? How to avoid duplicate entries

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of lists right now in python, containing the results of some calculation between every element of a 2D numpy array. (I found the difference between every value in the 2D array).
In an effort to be efficient and only perform this calculation once (since the absolute difference between X and Y is the same for both X and Y, this should only be calculated once),

I went through and got a big list of results.

To give you an idea, say I'm working with one variable in my array:

> [
>      [a],  {Other stuff is here(more variables), but they can be ignored for the example}
>      [b],   ~~
>      [c],   ~~
>      [d],   ~~
>      [e],   ~~
>   ]

^(where a, b,c... are actual numbers)

I need to find the absolute difference between every value of this variable, so I did, and put the results as they were computed together in a list of lists like this:

> [
>      [(a-b), (a-c), (a-d), (a-e)],
>      [(b-c), (b-d), (b-e)],
>      [(c-d), (c-e)],
>      [(d-e)],
>      ]

What I want to have is:

> [
>      [(a-b), (a-c), (a-d), (a-e)],
>      [(b-a), (b-c), (b-d), (b-e)],
>      [(c-a), (c-b), (c-d), (c-e)],
>      [(d-a), (d-b), (d-c), (d-e)],
>      ]

But notice how, since I'm working with absolute difference (e.g. absolute_value(a-b) ),
I shouldn't have to go through the list again and recompute the differences, 
since abs(a-b) is the same as abs(b-a).

Ideally, I also shouldn't have to store the number abs(a-b) twice either!
In regular python lists, I can set the value of a list to point to another list's value,
like:

> .>>> lemons = [1,2,3,4,5]
>   .>>> oranges= [999]
>   .>>> oranges[0] = lemons
>   .>>> oranges
>   [[1,2,3,4,5]]

In this way, the values [1,2,3,4,5] are only stored in lemons; oranges simply references these values. Namely, there exists a link between the two lists.
Is such a thing possible in a numpy array?
It would look something like:

> [
>      [(a-b),                           (a-c), (a-d), (a-e)],
>      [(link to [0,0]),                 (b-c), (b-d), (b-e)],
>      [(link to [0,1], (link to [1,1]), (c-b), (c-d), (c-e)],
>      [(etc),           (etc),          (etc), (etc), (d-e)],
>      ]

So values aren't stored twice. I'm working with a pretty large amount of values, so it really matters to me that they aren't stored twice.
If numpy cannot support this, do you have any other suggestions regarding how I might go about this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This would be much clearer (meaning you are more likely to get an answer) if you can provide a small example of your input as copy-paste-runnable Python code and your expected output. As it stands there is a lot of guesswork involved needed to provide any kind of answer.

Comment: This is what they talk about when they warn you about premature optimization... The code you are describing is going to be slower (because it will use Python loops) and use more memory (because it will store Python objects instead of raw number values, and anyway pointers take about as much space as the values they will be pointing to) than the naive numpy implementation you have discarded without trying it out. If you really need to cut operations in half, take a look at [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html).

Answer (score 0):

This might work as you wanted it:

```
A = [i for i in range(10)]
B = [i for i in range(10,20)]

R = [ [ abs(a-b) for b in B[i-len(B):] ] for i,a in enumerate(A)  ]
```

if you only need the first column of A then of course you can change it to

```
R = [ [ abs(a[0]-b) for b in B[i-len(B):] ] for i,a in enumerate(A)  ]
```

but I think performance wise using numpy for this, even at the cost of computing everything twice this:

```
A = np.arange(10)
B = np.arange(10,20)

R = abs(A[:,None] - B[None,:])
```

will win pretty quickly as it is done in C speed. If you really need to do what you proposed you might want to think about Cython.